# Browser can't find www.dnndev.me to install DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I am working with asp.net and I want to install DotNetnuke (I really need to install it). I have installed it on another computer in the company where I am doign my internship there. But I can't install it on my laptop :@.

First of all I have installed IIS (7.5 didn't worked, after that 8.0) and went through the steps in the 4 part video on how to install dotnetnuke (here is the first part: [First Part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5C2VX6Lbgg))

After I did all that, I went to start the isntallation by typing www.dnndev.me on the browser... and I got the error http 500.19 error.... I fixed it by checking some options in the Turn Widnows features on or of (at Programs and Features in Control Panel). 
After that I got the error http 500.21 .... I also fixed this by executing aspnet_regiis.exe.

And after executing that .exe file, when I typed www.dnndev.me, all errors where gone... but the Browser couldn't find www.dnndev.me !! I tried it on Chrome, Mozilla and IE... but non of them worken :(..

What's the problem? I removed all the errors, I did all the things in the videos.... why not working on my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the binding to IIS for DNNDEV.ME as well as WWW.DNNDEV.ME? The video instructs you to use DNNDEV.ME which is different than WWW.DNNDEV.ME, so you will need to add the binding for WWW if you want to access that.

Right click on the website in IIS, choose Edit Bindings and add the new one there.